# C integer to binary bit order

Tags: c, struct, binary

Below C program display binary representation of inputted decimal number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union {
    int i;
    struct {
        unsigned int dgts: 31;
        unsigned int sign: 1;
    } bin;
} myint;

void printb(int n, int i) {
    int k;

    for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        if ((n >> k) & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
}

void display_binary(myint x) {
    printf("%d | ", x.bin.sign);
    printb(x.bin.dgts, 31);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    myint decimal;

    printf("input decimal value : ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal.i);

    printf("Binary representation is:\n");
    display_binary(decimal);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is working correctly. What I can't understand is order of `dgts` and `sign` members of `bin` struct. Intuitively, `sign` member should precede `dgts` as bits that representing data are ordered from left to write in memory (as far as I know). After swapping orders of these two members, result became false. Why `dgts` should come before `sign`?

Comment: Because the bit usage is assigned from bit 0 upwards. The `sign: 1` member is the last (top) bit.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that decimal 1 is represented as "00000000000000000000000000000001"(leftmost 0 indication plus sign) in the memory. So you suggest that it is actually represented as "00000000000000000000000000000010" (righmost 0 plus sign, others digits)?

Comment: No, if you have, say `unsigned int data: 4;` that will use bits 0,1,2 and 3.

Comment: "bits that representing data are ordered from left to write in memory" No. There is no such thing as left or write in memory. There is only "lower address" and "higher address". Everything else is an assumption. Misagreeings on these assumptions have led to serious mistakes. There is no "obvious" when it comes to endianess. The more obvious it seems to you the more vulnerable you are to the corresponding mistakes. So better try to get rid of all thinking in that direction.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov negative numbers are stored a bit more "tricky" way. https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zjfgjxs/revision/5

Answer (score 1):

1. order of bits in the bitfields is implementation-defined, but most popular compilers start with LSB.
2. Numbers are stored binary and it does not matter how you enter them. Negative numbers are stored as two'2 complement on most modern systems. In this system, the sign bit does not exist "per se". No special types are needed

I would implement it as

```
void printb(int n) {
    unsigned int mask = 1U << (sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT - 1);

    for (; mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        printf("%c", (n & mask) ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```